# Why does libncurses ui not display when capturing to Bash variable?

Tags: bash, ncurses

I've written a libcurses-based ascii ui that writes text to stdout when the program exits.

If I execute the program alone, like so...

`> ./test`

...the ui displays.

However, if I try to capture the program output to a Bash variable, like so...

`> foo=$(./test)`

...the ui does not display, however the Bash variable captures the expected output.

Does anyone know why this behavior is as such? Is there a way to get the ui to show up when trying to capture its stdout to a Bash variable?

**The Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WINDOW* pWindow = initscr();
    keypad(pWindow, TRUE);
    curs_set(0);
    nodelay(pWindow, FALSE);

    mvwprintw(pWindow, 5, 5, "hello, world!");
    mvwprintw(pWindow, 6, 5, "hello, fold!");
    mvwprintw(pWindow, 7, 5, "hello, toad!");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        mvwprintw(pWindow, 5 + i, 1, "==>");

        refresh();

        usleep(500000);

        mvwprintw(pWindow, 5 + i, 1, "   ");
        refresh();
    }

    endwin();

    std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because redirecting the std output  (`>`, `a=$(…)`) just redirects the standard output – ncurses, on the other hand, directly talks to the terminal and displays characters, that never are part of stdout.

Short: it doesn't capture the output because there is none. Instead, ncurses programs directly talk to the underlying terminal.

> Is there a way to get the ui to show up when trying to capture its stdout to a Bash variable?

I don't recommend that. Because you're mixing non-interactive usage (getting std output) and interactive, and that can't really go well in the end, but:

you can end your ncurses session and just use `printf` like any other C programmer. Then you'd actually be producing std output.

I'd much rather just add an option to my program that takes a file to which I write my output. Then the bash script could open that file after my program has run.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to pull off what I'm trying to do? I.e. display the ui followed by an immediate and automatic capture of the stdout to a Bash variable? I'm not expert enough with *nix and/or Bash to think of ways this can be done.

Comment: "I'd much rather just add an option to my program that takes a file to which I write my output. Then the bash script could open that file after my program has run."  -- Got you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize curses using [`initscr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr), it will use the standard output for display.  (You *could* use [`newterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-newterm) to specify another output).  So when you redirect the output of the program you will not see the user-interface.

Adapting your example,

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ -o test foo.c $(ncursesw6-config --cflags --libs)
foo=$(./test)
set >foo.log
```

and looking at what bash puts in `$foo`, I see the expected control characters which are written in the user interface, e.g.,

```
foo=$'\E[?1049h\E[1;40r\E(B\E[m\E[4l\E[?7h\E[?1h\E=\E[?25l\E[H\E[2J\E[6d ==> hello, world!\n\E[6Ghello, fold!\n\E[6Ghello, toad!\E[6;5H\r    \r\n ==>\r    \r\n ==>\r    \r\n ==>\r\E[J    \r\n ==>\r\E[J    \E[40;1H\E[?12l\E[?25h\E[?1049l\r\E[?1l\E>bar'
```

Comment: Your answer is mostly correct :) no, seriously, ncurses uses the *virtual term* attached to stdout by default, but not stdout – and that might or might not be the same thing (i.e. the control characters that you captured), or actually be something crazy like ioctls controlling a terminal device